# Eating back burned calories?

Tags: diet, calories

As a skinny fat, I set my daily calories intake to 2000 calories to lose some fat which is minus 200 compared to my normal intake.

If I go to the gym, should I eat back the burned calories ?
In other words : If I burn 200 calorie, should my intake goes to 2200 on gym days ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 2200 calories is the amount of calories your body currently needs to maintain your current weight (see [Basal Metabolic Rate](https://www.healthline.com/health/what-is-basal-metabolic-rate)), and you are burning 200 calories at the gym, you can still lose weight consuming 2200 calories. This is because you would technically be in a 200 calorie deficit. If you abstain from consuming those 200 calories (stick to 2000/day) you would lose weight more quickly since your deficit would be 400. Your body will give you signals (fatigue, strong hunger urges) if it really needs more calories than you're providing, so listen to your body on if you should reduce your caloric deficit.

TL;DR: Assuming 2200 calorie maintenance level (BMR) with 200 extra calories burned daily from exercise, you would still lose weight eating 2200 calories